# JQuery Mobile: data-direction="reverse" not emulating initial transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate, transition

I have a back button in my header that looks like:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse"
data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Back</a>
```

The transition to get to this page is `slide` and, according to the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html), adding   `data-direction="reverse"` to my back button should 'reverse' the transition that got me to that page, ie: the previous page should slide back. However, this seems to be stuck just on the default `fade` transition. Is there something I have done wrong in setting this button up? Should I have a different kind of href?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
data-rel="back"

<a href="/" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
```

Also I think in order for "reverse" to work you must reference the exact previous URL/page. So if your page1 is "/" then you went to page2 and on page2 you have href="index.html" it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

What you can also do is declare the transition, so the reverse will work

```
<a href="index.htm" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide">Cancel</a>
```

In my case, this link is 2 pages after, so `data-rel="back"` was not what I was looking for