# JQuery Mobile data-direction=reverse isn't reversing

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I found this question and searched it and found two answers already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535296/jquery-mobile-data-direction-reverse-not-emulating-initial-transition) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573283/is-there-an-alternative-to-data-direction-reverse-something-like-a-slidelef), but neither of these are working for me. I am using phonegap with JQM 1.4.0 and I only get forward transitions when going back. My code looks like this:

```
<a href="event-list.html" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">BACK</a>
```

And for some reason I am only getting forward transitions and not the reverse.

edit: I also am not able to do a different transition going back then the transition I used going forward. I tried setting `data-transition="flow"` going forward and keeping the back button `data-transition="slide"` and I get a flow transition (and not the reverse transition) when going back as well.

Comment: it should work normally IF there is a page in UrlHistory before the current page. If you just want to reverse a transition, you dont need to add `data-rel="back"`. If there's a page in UrlHistory, `data-rel="back"` is enough, unless you want to apply a different transition, in this case, transition will be reversed by default.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a page in URLHistory. I can take out the href and just have the data-rel="back" and it still goes back. I added the href because someone in a previous thread suggested you needed it.

Comment: Are you using _single page_ or _multi-page_ model? what I meant by page in history, that you have moved from a page to the current page.

Comment: I am using a multi-page model. Yes I have moved from event-list.html to event-description.html and now trying to navigate back.

Comment: This is a _Single page_ model (multi html files). Once you move from an _external_ page it gets removed from DOM. I'm not sure whether it's caused by this. Have you moved to next page with `slide` transition or different one?

Comment: I have tried moving from pageA to pageB with a slide transition and a fade transition. When I transition back to pageA it seems to ignore the transition I tell it for going back and uses the same transition I specified for going forward from pageA to pageB. Also, on pageA, I have specified data-dom-cache="true" so it shouldn't be removed from the DOM. But I suspected that piece as well and have tried it both with and without caching with no success.

Comment: PageA to PageB transition will be applied. You can override it in one case, using `$.mobile.pageContainer` change function. Because, on `pagebeforechange` event it reads `$.mobile.navigation.History` and fetches PageA details and accordingly it changes page.

Comment: How would you do it using the change function? I tried calling $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', 'event-list.html'); but I have no idea how to attach a page transition.

Comment: try the code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c74SF/

Comment: Tried the code. Still no dice. I have also stripped out everything not relative to the problem just to make sure that nothing is conflicting and try to get to a sanity state. Even with a bare bones skeleton I can't get a reverse transition...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47781/discussion-between-omar-and-chase-roberts)

Comment: So it seems to work on android. But on iOS it still doesn't. But it's  not a huge issue for me.